# from urllib3 HTTPSConnectionPool request_encode_body certificate issue

Tags: python, ssl

I'm trying to sent a request on https url to get data, the domain needs security certificate when I try to execute it on the browser.

**But my issue is how to call the url on my python code to get the response data?
I've write the follwing code:**

```
conn = HTTPSConnectionPool(BETTING_CONFG['api_url'],
                               maxsize = BETTING_CONFG['connection_max_size'])

response = conn.request_encode_body('POST', service_uri, headers= headers,
                                         encode_multipart=False,  body = body)
```

**and I get the following response:**

```
Response: status = 200, payload = {"_status":"error","payload":{"_code":"0-2","_message":"invalid_app_key"}} .
```

**and this warning on the terminal:**

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:318: SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI (Subject Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform. This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate, which can cause validation failures. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#snimissingwarning.
  SNIMissingWarning
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:122: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:821: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html
  InsecureRequestWarning)
[555WIN] 2016-05-30 14:02:06,043 - INFO - Betting Response: status = 200, payload = {"_status":"error","payload":{"_code":"0-2","_message":"invalid_app_key"}} .
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/handlers.py", line 76, in emit
    if self.shouldRollover(record):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/handlers.py", line 156, in shouldRollover
    msg = "%s\n" % self.format(record)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 724, in format
    return fmt.format(record)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 464, in format
    record.message = record.getMessage()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 324, in getMessage
    msg = str(self.msg)
TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type dict)
Logged from file jsonapi.py, line 137
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 851, in emit
    msg = self.format(record)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 724, in format
    return fmt.format(record)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 464, in format
    record.message = record.getMessage()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 324, in getMessage
    msg = str(self.msg)
TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type dict)
```

when I added the certificate on the chrome and tried to send the request on the postman, it works fine?

any help how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please understand the your Chrome certificate store is not the same certificate store that is used by your Python application.

It would be much easier if you could only get a valid SSL certificate instead of trying to make self-signed ones to work.

Also, be sure you do upgrade your Python and urllib. Those warning messages are not to be ignored! Resolve them first!

SSL certificates used to be expensive but now you can get valid, fully supported certificates for **free** from [LetsEncrypt](https://letsencrypt.org). I run my [own website](https://sbarnea.com) using their certificates and I can assure you that Python does have no problem loading their certificates.